# как открыть JFrame во весь экран и перекрыть панель задач? Swing

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Подскажите пожалуйста. как открыть JFrame окно и перекрыть панель задач винды?

Спасибо.

Код:

```
public class Main extends JFrame {
    public Main() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {

        panel1 = new JPanel();
        button1 = new JButton();
        button2 = new JButton();

        //======== this ========
        Container contentPane = getContentPane();
        contentPane.setLayout(new GridLayout());

        //======== panel1 ========
        {

            //---- button1 ----
            button1.setText("1");

            //---- button2 ----
            button2.setText("2");

            GroupLayout panel1Layout = new GroupLayout(panel1);
            panel1.setLayout(panel1Layout);
            panel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                panel1Layout.createParallelGroup()
                    .addGroup(panel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(button1)
                        .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(button2)
                        .addContainerGap(295, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            );
            panel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
                panel1Layout.createParallelGroup()
                    .addGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, panel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap(230, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addGroup(panel1Layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(button1)
                            .addComponent(button2))
                        .addContainerGap())
            );
        }
        contentPane.add(panel1);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(getOwner());
    }

    private JPanel panel1;
    private JButton button1;
    private JButton button2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();

        main.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        main.setUndecorated(true);
        main.setVisible(true);

        /*GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        GraphicsDevice gs = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();

        gs.setFullScreenWindow(main);

        main.setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        main.setVisible(true);*/
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);   
frame.setUndecorated(true);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Или вот еще вариант.
Объявляете переменную:

```
static GraphicsDevice device = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices()[0];
```

И в конструкторе пишем:

```
    device.setFullScreenWindow(frame);
```

Comment: ловлю ошибку при запуске:

`Exception in thread "main" java.awt.IllegalComponentStateException: The frame is displayable.
 at java.awt.Frame.setUndecorated(Frame.java:923)
 at com.tsyklop.Main.main(Main.java:42)`

Comment: Думаю, Вы поставили setUndecorated(true); после setVisible(true);

Comment: я скопировал всё как вы написали.

Comment: добавьте в первый пост кусок кода, как это у Вас выглядит

Comment: добавил в шапку

Comment: перенесите методы в конструктор Main() {сюда}, и имя main замените на this

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59838/discussion-between-plem-and-tsyklop).